# Implement ListView in android Widgets

Tags: android, widget

I am making a widget for one of my applications which includes a `ListView`.

I want to display a list of 2 records on my widget.
I have searched many forums and tutorials but could not find any tutorial on `ListViews` in widgets.

Can any one provide me with some good code/tutorials from where i can learn to implement `ListViews` in Android Widgets.

Comment: try this ([adding views to linearlayout][1])


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078039/remoteview-addview-not-working

Answer (score 22, accepted):

CommonsGuy has a sample widget application in `GitHub` using a `ListView` in a homescreen widget: [LoremWidget](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget)

Comment: That example seems not to run on my Droid Bionic

Comment: i am using LoremWidget right now. how can i get a refernce to the listview there?  getListView() does nothing :/

Comment: that sample now has properly specified its min sdk as 11 (3.x) https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/commit/e0d2dde51bb651500a5b84fcd2c30c70e0dd4404

Comment: I tried to use this, but I got problems. I tried to discribe them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713373/listview-in-widget-adds-randomly-items-on-scrolling-and-resizing

Answer (score -1):

Bit late in the day but I've just done this using 3 horizontal linearlayouts within a vertical ll. Set each of the horizontal lls to visibility  GONE and then just set visibility to VISIBLE and set text for each one you want to show

Doesn't use a listview but achieves the same end.