# How to create Listview with help of remoteview?

Tags: android, listview, notifications, remoteview

I am trying to make dynamic `listview` in widget with help of `remoteview`, as I wanted this `listview` of application icons in a widget. I want to show incoming notifications from all apps which are separated application wise. I want to create standing notification list and when user clicks on application icon from listview, that particular notification will be displayed. I am using `API 19` for getting all notification and also succeeded but I don't know how I can create `Listview` in widget with `Remoteview` and also with `drawables(Icons)`.

Comment: Have you done any code yet?

Comment: Any?? A lot code and java files i have tried...

Comment: Here's another useful answer: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/6093753/2180161 - it was easier for me to understand this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you search or try with other examples having ListView in widget?
Please check the **[Weather Widget demo](https://github.com/manishcm/weatherwidget)** available on github.

Code:

```
    public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static HandlerThread sWorkerThread;
    private static Handler sWorkerQueue;

    public MyWidgetProvider() {
        // Start the worker thread
        sWorkerThread = new HandlerThread("MyWidgetProvider-worker");
        sWorkerThread.start();
        sWorkerQueue = new Handler(sWorkerThread.getLooper());
    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
            ...
            final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lvWidget, svcIntent);

            sWorkerQueue.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    views.setScrollPosition(R.id.list, 3);
                    appWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
                }

            }, 1000);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Which will behave like below:

[image]

Please check the github project and above sample code.

Comment: @kiturk3 Please let me know if this answer not resolved your question or please accept it as right one so that other can also come to know about that and have right direction to their implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Actually i wanted to do this for samsung galaxy note edge panel. I had already read your same nswer in another question but that did't work exactly. I had to tweak something extra but it was sure helpful.
Thank you :)

Comment: with help of cade i answered, it gives me listview and that's exactly 70% i needed. Only i have to implement onclickpendingintent event into that.

Comment: ok. So where is the issue with that? You can send bundle with the onclicklistener that which item you have clicked. As per that you can also handled the action you want.

Comment: Here's another useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6093753/2180161 - it was easier for me to understand this one

Answer (score 1):

I had already tried from @iDroid Explorer's solution from one of his previous answers. But listview was not showing up in edge panel(PS: I wanted this to implement in galaxy note edge's panel ).

So i tried below code:

```
    private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context arg0, int i) {

        //which layout to show on widget
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(arg0.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.activity_main_sub);

        //RemoteViews Service needed to provide adapter for ListView
        Log.d("fff", "updateWidget: "+ i);

        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(arg0, MyService.class);

        //passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
        svcIntent.putExtra("Id", i);
        Log.d("fff", "receiver:"+appnM);
        svcIntent.putExtra("appname", appnM);
        //setting a unique Uri to the intent
        //don't know its purpose to me right now
        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        //setting adapter to listview of the widget

        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(i, R.id.list_icon,svcIntent);

//      remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(i, svcIntent);

        arg0.startService(svcIntent);
        //setting an empty view in case of no data
        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.list_icon, R.id.empty_view);

        Log.d("fff","end of myReceiver");
        return remoteViews;
    }
```

And in myService class i have populated required items in list.

I got help from an example called: WidgetListView1, which i found from random searches.