# Android-Using RecyclerView inside the widget

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, widget

I want to use recyclerview inside the widget (like GMail widget does). I've created RecyclerAdapter class, recycleritem layout and widget layout with LinearLayout as a root view. All seems to be fine but I don't know how to access those layouts from widget where remoteviews are available only. Here is the code where I'm stuck:

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.schedule_today_widget);

        ScheduleActivity scheduleActivity = new ScheduleActivity();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int week = scheduleActivity.currentWeek(context);
        ArrayList<Lesson> mDataSet = scheduleActivity.getDataSet(week, day, context);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) views ...

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
```

Thank you.

== Edit ==
I want to access recyclerview and recycleradapter from widget's update method. In regular activity I'd have done it like this:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.schedule_monday_card);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new ScheduleRecyclerAdapter(myDatasetMonday, context);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But I can't do this inside of this method cause context does not let me use findViewById() or anything.

== Edit ==

Okay, now I should use ListView. But I still don't know how to access my ListView in widget's layout from onUpdate method?

Comment: Your question is quite vague in my opinion, little bit of explanation could help some of us; what layouts do you want to access?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [App Widgets documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout), RecyclerView is not among supported views when using remote views. I am pretty sure that you should use ListView instead, and that Gmail and other similar widgets does so.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Totally forgot about ListViews. Thank you!

Comment: Well, now I don't know how to access ListView in my widget's layout :D

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093256/implement-listview-in-android-widgets